# What does fs and gs registers provide in Linux?

Tags: assembly, x86, linux

In a 64 bit ELF binary I found it mainly uses `fs` register to get some values. How can I know which value it wants to access? I'm familiar with that NT kernel uses `fs` and `gs` register for [TEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) structure in 32 bit and 64 bit OS respectively.

Here are two examples:

1.

```
mov rax, fs:28h
mov [rsp+88], rax
```

2.

```
sub_a proc near
mov rax, fs:0
add rax, 44h
retn
sub_a endp
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `gs`/`fs` [segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) can be used for [thread local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) similar to what you have encountered in Windows. Variable specific to a thread such as `errno`, [stack canary](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/arch/x86/include/asm/stackprotector.h) etc are usually stored here in Linux.

According to [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/arch/x86/include/asm/stackprotector.h), your first example is to save canary to the stack from `fs:0x28`. You can see some hacks [here](https://github.com/zardus/preeny/blob/master/src/getcanary.c) and read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611346/how-are-the-fs-gs-registers-used-in-linux-amd64)

Canary check from an example binary

```
$ tail x.c 

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char s[32];
    scanf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -no-pie -fno-pic x.c -o z64   
$ gcc -m32 -no-pie -fno-pic x.c -o z32   
$ r2 -AA z32 -qc "pdf @ sym.main"     
            ;-- main:
┌ (fcn) sym.main 86
....
│           0x080484bf      65a114000000   mov eax, dword gs:[0x14]    ; [0x14:4]=-1 ; 20
│           0x080484c5      8945f4         mov dword [local_ch], eax
│           0x080484c8      31c0           xor eax, eax
....
│           0x080484e3      8b55f4         mov edx, dword [local_ch]
│           0x080484e6      653315140000.  xor edx, dword gs:[0x14]
│       ┌─< 0x080484ed      7405           je 0x80484f4
│       │   0x080484ef      e85cfeffff     call sym.imp.__stack_chk_fail ; void __stack_chk_fail(void)
....
$ r2 -AA z64 -qc "pdf @ sym.main"
            ;-- main:
┌ (fcn) sym.main 79
....
│           0x00400586      64488b042528.  mov rax, qword fs:[0x28]    ; [0x28:8]=-1 ; '(' ; 40
│           0x0040058f      488945f8       mov qword [local_8h], rax
│           0x00400593      31c0           xor eax, eax
....
│           0x004005b0      488b55f8       mov rdx, qword [local_8h]
│           0x004005b4      644833142528.  xor rdx, qword fs:[0x28]
│       ┌─< 0x004005bd      7405           je 0x4005c4
│       │   0x004005bf      e8acfeffff     call sym.imp.__stack_chk_fail ; void __stack_chk_fail(void)
....
```

Also for your second request, yes that is [`pthread_t`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/sys_types.h.0p.html) at offset 0 in `fs`/`gs`.

```
$ tail -n 30 x.c

#ifdef __x86_64__
#define val_t     uint64_t
#define INSN_READ    "movq %%fs:0, %0;"
#define FMT          "Found val: %#lx\n"

#elif __i386__
#define val_t     uint32_t
#define INSN_READ    "movl %%gs:0, %0;"
#define FMT          "Found val: %#x\n"
#endif

val_t read_val()
{
    val_t val = 0;

    __asm__(INSN_READ
        : "=r"(val)
        :
        :);

    return val;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf(FMT, read_val());
    printf(FMT, (val_t)pthread_self());
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -no-pie -fno-pic x.c -o zm64
$ gcc -m32 -no-pie -fno-pic x.c -o zm32

$ ./zm32 
Found val: 0xf7f800c0
Found val: 0xf7f800c0

$ ./zm64 
Found val: 0x7fd50119f4c0
Found val: 0x7fd50119f4c0
```

I tried to look for your second snippet in my `libc` but couldn't find it. SO can't answer for sure what it contains at `0x44`. While debugging I only got 0s at that offset.

```
  $ r2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
   -- There is only one binary, and we are all just reversing pieces of it.
  [0x00021cb0]> /x `!rasm2 -a x86.as -b 64 "mov rax, fs:[0]"`
  Searching 9 bytes in [0x0-0x1e6aa0]
  hits: 7
  Searching 9 bytes in [0x3e7620-0x3f0ae0]
  hits: 0
  0x000e18c9 hit0_0 64488b042500000000
  0x000e1d8a hit0_1 64488b042500000000
  0x00105cff hit0_2 64488b042500000000
  0x00105e50 hit0_3 64488b042500000000
  0x00105f21 hit0_4 64488b042500000000
  0x00106865 hit0_5 64488b042500000000
  0x0014a18a hit0_6 64488b042500000000
  [0x00021cb0]> pd10 @@ hit0_*
              ;-- hit0_0:
              0x000e18c9      64488b042500.  mov rax, qword fs:[0]
              0x000e18d2      31db           xor ebx, ebx
              0x000e18d4      48c744241800.  mov qword [rsp + 0x18], 0
              0x000e18dd      4c8b25849530.  mov r12, qword [0x003eae68] ; [0x3eae68:8]=0
              0x000e18e4      48890424       mov qword [rsp], rax
              0x000e18e8      488d442450     lea rax, [rsp + 0x50]       ; "@" ; 'P'
              0x000e18ed      4889442430     mov qword [rsp + 0x30], rax
              0x000e18f2      488d442460     lea rax, [rsp + 0x60]       ; '`'
              0x000e18f7      4889442420     mov qword [rsp + 0x20], rax
              0x000e18fc      488d442458     lea rax, [rsp + 0x58]       ; "@" ; 'X'
              ;-- hit0_1:
              0x000e1d8a      64488b042500.  mov rax, qword fs:[0]
              0x000e1d93      31db           xor ebx, ebx
              0x000e1d95      48c744242800.  mov qword [rsp + 0x28], 0
              0x000e1d9e      4c8b25c39030.  mov r12, qword [0x003eae68] ; [0x3eae68:8]=0
              0x000e1da5      4889442410     mov qword [rsp + 0x10], rax
              0x000e1daa      488d442460     lea rax, [rsp + 0x60]       ; '`'
              0x000e1daf      4889442440     mov qword [rsp + 0x40], rax
              0x000e1db4      488d442470     lea rax, [rsp + 0x70]       ; 'p'
              0x000e1db9      4889442430     mov qword [rsp + 0x30], rax
              0x000e1dbe      488d442468     lea rax, [rsp + 0x68]       ; 'h'
              ;-- hit0_2:
              0x00105cff      64488b042500.  mov rax, qword fs:[0]
              0x00105d08      488b1d41512e.  mov rbx, qword [0x003eae50] ; [0x3eae50:8]=0
              0x00105d0f      4c8b2d52512e.  mov r13, qword [0x003eae68] ; [0x3eae68:8]=0
              0x00105d16      4c8d3c18       lea r15, [rax + rbx]
              0x00105d1a      48898560feff.  mov qword [rbp - 0x1a0], rax
              0x00105d21      4c89e7         mov rdi, r12
              0x00105d24      e807060600     call sym._dl_mcount_wrapper_check
              0x00105d29      488b8560feff.  mov rax, qword [rbp - 0x1a0]
              0x00105d30      4883ec08       sub rsp, 8
              0x00105d34      498b4e08       mov rcx, qword [r14 + 8]    ; sym.__resp ; [0x8:8]=0
              ;-- hit0_3:
              0x00105e50      64488b042500.  mov rax, qword fs:[0]
              0x00105e59      4c8b2d08502e.  mov r13, qword [0x003eae68] ; [0x3eae68:8]=0
              0x00105e60      4c8dbd98feff.  lea r15, [rbp - 0x168]
              0x00105e67      488b1de24f2e.  mov rbx, qword [0x003eae50] ; [0x3eae50:8]=0
              0x00105e6e      48c78598feff.  mov qword [rbp - 0x168], 0
              0x00105e79      48898560feff.  mov qword [rbp - 0x1a0], rax
              0x00105e80      4c01e8         add rax, r13                ; 'o'
              0x00105e83      48898508feff.  mov qword [rbp - 0x1f8], rax
              0x00105e8a      660f1f440000   nop word [rax + rax]
              0x00105e90      4c89e7         mov rdi, r12
              ;-- hit0_4:
              0x00105f21      64488b042500.  mov rax, qword fs:[0]
              0x00105f2a      4c8b2d374f2e.  mov r13, qword [0x003eae68] ; [0x3eae68:8]=0
              0x00105f31      4c8dbd98feff.  lea r15, [rbp - 0x168]
              0x00105f38      488b1d114f2e.  mov rbx, qword [0x003eae50] ; [0x3eae50:8]=0
              0x00105f3f      48c78598feff.  mov qword [rbp - 0x168], 0
              0x00105f4a      48898560feff.  mov qword [rbp - 0x1a0], rax
              0x00105f51      4c01e8         add rax, r13                ; 'o'
              0x00105f54      48898508feff.  mov qword [rbp - 0x1f8], rax
              0x00105f5b      0f1f440000     nop dword [rax + rax]
              0x00105f60      4c89e7         mov rdi, r12
              ;-- hit0_5:
              0x00106865      64488b042500.  mov rax, qword fs:[0]
              0x0010686e      488db5c0feff.  lea rsi, [rbp - 0x140]
              0x00106875      4c8b0dd4452e.  mov r9, qword [0x003eae50]  ; [0x3eae50:8]=0
              0x0010687c      488b8d20feff.  mov rcx, qword [rbp - 0x1e0]
              0x00106883      ba00010000     mov edx, 0x100
              0x00106888      4885ff         test rdi, rdi
              0x0010688b      490f44fd       cmove rdi, r13
              0x0010688f      4901c1         add r9, rax                 ; '#'
              0x00106892      480305cf452e.  add rax, qword [0x003eae68]
              0x00106899      4989c0         mov r8, rax
              ;-- hit0_6:
              0x0014a18a      64488b042500.  mov rax, qword fs:[0]
              0x0014a193      4c89fb         mov rbx, r15
              0x0014a196      4889442440     mov qword [rsp + 0x40], rax
              0x0014a19b      488d442460     lea rax, [rsp + 0x60]       ; '`'
              0x0014a1a0      4889442408     mov qword [rsp + 8], rax
              0x0014a1a5      488b4500       mov rax, qword [rbp]
              0x0014a1a9      488b7c2458     mov rdi, qword [rsp + 0x58] ; [0x58:8]=64 ; 'X'
              0x0014a1ae      4889442410     mov qword [rsp + 0x10], rax
              0x0014a1b3      488b03         mov rax, qword [rbx]
              0x0014a1b6      4889442418     mov qword [rsp + 0x18], rax
  [0x00021cb0]>
```

Comment: Thank you for the full answer. One side-question. I've not found the definition of pthread structure to get the variable at `rax + 0x44`.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I added a link. The definition of that type ought to be in `sys/types.h` (e.g. in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h`) ... which in turn includes `pthreadtypes.h` (e.g. `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h`) which has `typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;`. But mind that this is system/architecture-specific.

Comment: @Biswapriyo did you actually head to the files I pointed out? There is an interesting comment just above the definition of `pthread_t` which I gave you above ...

Comment: I found the answer. The `rax+0x40` is the offset of `errno` (4 bytes takes `rax+0x44`). There may be some relation between `pthread` and `errno`.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, Where did you find this info? I need rax+0x3c, but do not find also, what you succeeded

Comment: @FERcsI the structure depends on the libc.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, I understand it, but probably, I can find it in a header or other compiler-specific file. And I was happy, you could figure it out for yourself, so maybe I can also do it with some hint :)