# Detecting and solutions of stack smash protection

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, gcc, stack-protector

This video https://youtube.com/watch?v=4HxUmbOcN6Y presents how modern compilers protect stack overflows with stack cookies and function `__stack_chk_fail`.

1. How can one identify if a binary has stack smashing protection? If I see  `__stack_chk_fail` in IDA can I guess that this binary uses stack cookies(I will see this function only if this binary compiled dynamically).

But if this function is compiled statically, how can I recognize it? Each function will end with `if ... then abort else return` or only functions that get buffer from user?

2. If binary use stack smash protection and get buffer unsafe (like `gets` ) how can I get over stack cookies? Or there is no way to return to another function?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can identify if a function is protected by the presence of `__stack_chk_fail`. It doesn't matter if it's user-custom code or it is statically compiled from libraries.
2. `gets` is a very problematic function by design. It's impossible to protect it from buffer overflows

For example:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[2000];
    gets(buf);
}
```

In this case, the stack protection will most likely be on the `main` function, because of the `buf` variable.

Comment: 1.  `__stack_chk_fail` it's part of `libssp` so if I compile it statically I will not see `__stack_chk_fail` in code.    2. If stack smash protection used and the code check the magic before return address in stack, how can I over write it and jump to another function even I use `gets`

Comment: 1. Compile statically means that the function resides within your compiled library, and not in an outside imported library. So it doesn't matter, you will still see a call to the function - once from within your file, and once as an import from outside. Don't be confused with `inline`

Comment: 2. Yes, this is the purpose of the stack check - if it's enabled you won't be able to exploit the potential overflow caused by `gets`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [checksec](https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh) for dynamically linked binaries. However it'll fail for statically compiled binaries. You can try something like this for x86/64 with radare2

- i386

```
$ r2 -AAA -qq -c "pdf @main~gs" test
│           0x00000591      658b0d140000.  mov ecx, dword gs:[0x14]
│           0x000005b6      65331d140000.  xor ebx, dword gs:[0x14]
```

- amd64

```
$ r2 -AAA -qq -c "pdf @main~fs" test
│           0x00400b5c      64488b042528.  mov rax, qword fs:[0x28]
│           0x00400b85      644833142528.  xor rdx, qword fs:[0x28]
```

In x64 cookie is loaded from `fs:[0x28]` and in x86 from `gs:[0x14]` in the function prolog. You can refer to the answer [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19979/what-does-fs-and-gs-registers-provide-in-linux/19983#19983)